# MacOS: How to switch panes between split terminal Window

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I know that I can split the Terminal into multiple panes. Opening a new pane can be done using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Closing a pane can be done using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The *problem* I am now facing is that all existing panes are synced. Meaning: If I type in one pane, the same text appears in all other open panes.

**Questions:**

1. How can I un-sync those panes?
2. How can I switch between panes?

It would be nice to have a keyboard-shortcut-answer for both questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to write a comment. But the answer is in this post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87202/how-to-switch-or-close-the-new-split-terminal-pane

The idea behind splitting is that it allows you to keep a certain part of the shell buffer displayed while continuing to enter new commands. So only the lowest split does allow keyboard input. To position the view on the shell buffer use the scroll bar.

You can un-split by pressing `Shift-Cmd-D`